Existence of Orthonormal Basis of Eigenvectors of Closed Operator Implies Diagonalizability?

Proposition: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A$ a closed (possibly unbounded) linear operator on $H$.
Let $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ an orthonormal basis of $H$ (contained in $\operatorname{dom} (A)$) with
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : A  \varphi_n = \lambda_n \varphi_n.
$$
Then $$ \forall x \in \operatorname{dom} (A) : A x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n \langle x, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n.$$

Question:
Is the proposition true? If it is, how can it be proven? If it is not
can you provide a counter example?
I am suspecting that the proposition is not true in general, but i can not come up with a counterexample. As a bonus question: Are there other conditions (other than the ones at the end of the question) on $A$ that imply that the conclusion of the proposition is true?
Partial progress:
If $A$ is everywhere defined, then $A$ is continuous (closed graph theorem) and the proposition is an easy consequence.
If $A$ is not everywhere defined consider the following:
Define a linear operator $B$ on $H$ by
$$
\operatorname{dom} (B) := \{ x \in H: \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\lambda_n \langle x, \varphi_n\rangle |^2 < \infty \} , \ Bx := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n \langle x, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n.
$$
Then $B$ is a (densely defined) normal operator (follows for example from Thm. 13.24 in grandpa Rudin).
Now the proposition is equivalent to showing that $A=B$ (because of this).
I managed to show $B \subset A$: Let $x \in \operatorname{dom} (B)$. Define a sequence in $H$ by $x_k := \sum_{n=1}^k \langle x, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n$, then $(x_k) \to x$ and $(A x_k) \to Bx $, hence $x \in \operatorname{dom} (A)$ and $Ax = Bx$, because $A$ is closed.
This allows to conclude the proposition in the following cases:

$A$ is symmetric, because then the $(\lambda_n)$ are real, implying that $B$ is self-adjoint, but self-adjoint operators are maximally symmetric, hence $A=B$.
$A$ is normal, because normal operators are maximally normal and $B$ is already normal and hence $B=A$.


No, this is not true in general. In fact, we have the following result:
Proposition: Let $B: \text{dom}(B) \to H$ be a closed operator with $\text{dom}(B) \neq H$. Then there exists a closed operator $A$ s.t. $B \subsetneq A$.
Proof: Let $x \in H \setminus \text{dom}(B)$. Then define $A$ with $\text{dom}(A) = \text{dom}(B) + \mathbb{C}x$ by,
$$A(\xi + \alpha x) = B\xi$$
for any $\xi \in \text{dom}(B)$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $x \notin \text{dom}(B)$, $A$ is well-defined. $A$ is also closed since its graph is,
$$\text{graph}(A) = \text{graph}(B) + \mathbb{C}(x, 0)$$
which is a closed subspace $\text{graph}(B)$ plus a one-dimensional subspace $\mathbb{C}(x, 0)$, whence closed itself. Finally, we clearly have $B \subsetneq A$. $\square$
Now apply the proposition above to $B$ constructed in your partial progress section. As long as $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ is not bounded, $B$ is not everywhere defined, and we get a closed operator $A$ with $B \subsetneq A$. Any such $A$ is clearly a counterexample.
